# Can I place a Booster Pump after Pressure Tank and before my water softener

Tags: plumbing

My current set-up:

- Well 150' deep with 2 HP submersible pump,
- 2000 Gal. Holding tank with 2 HP submersible pump,
- 80 Gal. Pressure tank set at 42/64 on pressure switch,

From the holding tank to the house is 350' with a 1" water line and a 40 foot elevation increase,
Water pressure at the house on the outside water bid is 38 PSI.

I want to install in the garage from the main water line in this order to increase the water pressure:

- Sediment filter,
- 1 & 1/2 HP booster pump and set the pressure switch at 30/50,
- Water Filter,
- Water softener.

By doing this in this order will this be OK.

I have one pump in the well and one pump in the holding tank. If I move the pressure tank to the house 350 feet away wouldn't I have to run another electrical line from the holding tank pump to the pressure tank in the house?

I do see what you are saying, and everything you said makes complete sense, which would spare me the cost of buying a booster pump if I move the pressure tank to the house.

But if I can't move the pressure tank to the house, can I still put a booster pump in the main (in) water line in the garage before my water softener?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post to update it with more information, or 'add a comment' underneath it or one of the answers to reply to someone who's posted here. Don't post your response as an answer; see the [tour] for a quick overview of how this site works. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

"John", you mentioned (2) 2HP. pumps. Do you actually have 2 pumps; 1 in the well and 1 in the storage tank? If you do, I would move the pressure tank from the storage tank area to inside the house, with the pump on/off settings would remain where you have them.  This way you would have 42/64 psi pressure in the house. If you do not have 2 pumps, I would add the booster pump at the storage tank and move the pressure tank to inside the house as I previously mentioned. This way the storage tank to the pressure tank would yield the water line pressure drop and you would not experience the pressure drop in the house The house pressure would always be between the pump on or off pressure switch settings. Adding an additional booster pump and pressure regulator would yield a steady house pressure at your desired setting.

Answer (score 0):

John, could you move the 2000 gallon holding to an area adjacent to the house then every thing except the well pump would be near the point of use? Or, by moving the pressure tank inside the house you would only have to run 2 wires from the pressure switch to the transfer pump to control it's operation. another thought; If you added a booster pump in the house before the water softner, it may make sense to add another holding/pressure tank before the booster pump to insure that the booster pump has a steady supply of water so the pump does not "cavitate". A cavitating pump will add noise to the system and shorten the life of the pump. If this was my home I would first try to move the 2000 gallon holding tank close to the house or second, move the pressure tank to the house and add the control wiring as necessary. Just giving my best thoughts.

Comment: Sir, sorry but the 2000 Gal. holding tank is in the ground and can't be moved. Moving the pressure tank to the house is not viable either. I can put another smaller pressure tank in the garage before the booster pump that would eliminate the possibility of the booster pump caviting. How does that sound?

Comment: sounds OK to me.

Comment: Move a 2000 gallon tank are you kidding?

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly I would add a booster and a second pressure tank at the house level. I say this because in the past I have installed deep wells with cisterns on multiple levels a pressure tank at the home that is supplied by a booster world great if the over all flow required to the house is less than the well's flow rate and a large enough tank or cistern for example we needed to pump about 500' above the well it was a low flow 2.5 gph with a large tank at the well and another half way up the pressure was two low so another tank was added and a pump, this house had 60 psi water for 3 hours, after that the cisterns or tanks below would run out, but for being able to get a loan on a multi million home site this worked as the local regulations only required 5 Gpm for 3 hours, as long as the well can provide the water you can pump it and finally provide the pressure you want/ need.